# What is the point of fixed point of a function/transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The fixed point of a function : $f(x)=x$.

Some functions have, some functions do not.
What is the use/significant of having the fixed point and not having it?

One of the fixed point i see is the linear transformation: $T(0)=0$. I do not know what this non-moving origin doing in the linear transformation. Is it preserve identity of addition?

Comment: Check out my [video](https://youtu.be/1BRf2LveEsY) for some examples.

Comment: @blargoner — great video!

Answer (score 1):

The existence of fixed points is related to function *[iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)* -- if a function $f(x)$ has a fixed point $c$ then $f(f(f(......f(c)...))) = c$ -- it is a point of stability.

This is very important in the analysis of system dynamics and control/equilibria, where you want to know if the fixed points are stable (i.e., function iteration always converges to that point) or unstable (see [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_(Chasnov)/08%3A_Nonlinear_Differential_Equations/8.01%3A_Fixed_Points_and_Stability#:%7E:text=A%20fixed%20point%2C%20however%2C%20can,stability%20by%20a%20linear%20analysis.)).

It is also involved in iterative algorithms in general, as their convergence/stopping criteria often implicitly assume you are approaching a stable fixed point.